# Can i use element's own property as argument for a plugin call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am implementing the [slim scroll plugin](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) on my page (it converts default scrollbars on scrollable divs into prettier ones), and the implementation call, as per their example, goes like this:

```
$('#inner-content-div').slimScroll({
   height: '250px'
});
```

Since i have a need for more scrollable divs of different heights, i would need to call this plugin several times, passing different height as an argument each time.

To minify so much code, make it more readable, but also to avoid having to change my JS when i change my CSS, can i use something along the lines of this:

```
$('#inner-content-div').slimScroll({
   height: $(this).css('height')
});
```

The above example, of course, doesn't work, it's just something i tried and it failed. But it should illustrate my intention.

Comment: the above will work only if you set a height for the item in css. otherwise `$(this).height();` will do

Comment: Well i do have the height in the css, i have to anyway, otherwise the div wouldn't have been scrollable to begin with... however it really doesn't read it, and if i use your code it works fine... Can i somehow accept a comment as the answer to my question on here? :P

Comment: lol no you cant, ill post it as an answer in a sec :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't as there is no scope that defines the value of `this` to be the element, but you can create such a scope with `each`

```
$('#inner-content-div').each(function() {
   $(this).slimScroll({
       height: $(this).css('height')
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code will work only if you set a height for the item in css. otherwise 
`$(this).height();`
 will do

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it actually doesn't do it 100% correctly. It implements the plugin successfully, but it reads the height wrong... I guess that's probably because of the scope issue from adeneo's answer, maybe it just assumes a height based on something. (sorry for making you post an unnecessary answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var myElem = $('#inner-content-div');
myElem.slimScroll({
   height: myElem.css('height')
});
```

This will work as you intend it to. Just assign the element and use it.